# how to buffer a batch of data in flink

Tags: apache-flink, clickhouse, data-stream

I want to buffer a datastream in flink. My initial idea is caching 100 pieces of data into a list or tuple and then using `insert into values (???)` to insert data into clickhouse in bulk. Do you have better ways to do this?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by buffer datastream? Do you want to collect data in a window (based on a time or amount of events) and them flush the events without aggregating them?

Comment: exactly...collect in a window and then flush them

Answer (score 2):

The first solution that you post works but it is flaky. It can lead to starvation due to a simplistic logic. For instance, let's say that you have a counter of `100` to create a batch. It is possible that your stream never receives `100` events, or it takes hours to receive the `100th` event. Then your basic and working solution can have events stuck in the window batch because it is a **count window**. In other words, your batch can generate windows of `30` seconds in a high throughput, or windows of `1` hour when your throughput is very low.

```
DataStream<User> stream = ...;
DataStream<Tuple2<User, Long>> stream1 = stream
    .countWindowAll(100)
    .process(new MyProcessWindowFunction());
```

In general, it depends on your use case. However, I would use a **time window** to make sure that my job always has the flush batch even though there are few or no events on the window.

```
DataStream<Tuple2<User, Long>> stream1 = stream
    .windowAll(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(30)))
    .process(new MyProcessWindowFunction());;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the answers. I use a window function to solve this problem.

```
SingleOutputStreamOperator<ArrayList<User>> stream2 = 
     stream1.countWindowAll(batchSize).process(new MyProcessWindowFunction());
```

Then I overwrite the process function in which the batch size of data is buffered in an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import data into the database in batches, you can use the window(countWindow or timeWindow)to aggregate the data.